# Capture image using Webcam and save to database in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Good day guys. I have been searching all night long for tutorials that involved capturing images using webcam then save that image to database. All I have been seeing were image path being saved to the database. I wanted the image itself being saved to the database server. Can you suggest any links/site that capture images then save to database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So are you having trouble only with saving the file to database ?

Comment: @Shyju Yes sir. I just wanted something that saves to the db itself

Comment: So you have HttpPostedFileBase object populated in your action method and you are looking for the code to save it to database ?

Comment: @Shyju I have none yet. All I have is a button, when clicked it will show a modal popup. Then the camera is there. I am only up to the taking of snap shot. No codes to saving the image to database yet.